# SQL error after CiviCRM 4.7.23 upgrade

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, civicrm

After upgrading from `CiviCRM 4.7.19 to 4.7.23`, views related to CiviCRM are failing to load. The following error is visible on the view configuration page:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
>   westernfriend_civicrm.civicrm_contact civicrm_contact LIMIT 1 OFFSET
>   0' at line 1

What should I do to resolve the above error, and restore our view functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the answer was to carefully read through the upgrade instructions (step 15):

15. Clear Views' cache (for sites using Views 3 integration)

    If you were using Views integration prior to this upgrade, you will need to go to Administration » Structure » Views » Settings » Advanced and press "Clear Views cache" for Views to capture changes in the CiviCRM Views integration code.